# The purpose of capacitor between positive and negative in TIA circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to know what is purpose of C1 in below transimpedance amplifier, and how you calculate it.

Without the C1 the output should be equal to :
Vout = VGND - Is*RF  (Vout can not exceed VCC)

Note: VGND is just voltage divider with buffer  which should be half of VCC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMBgue.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That C1 is not there in the general case. So, you'll have to ask the person who gave you this schematic, not us.

Comment: What is the left side of the circuit connected to, input S+ 9uA? 
My guess is that C1 is modeling parasitic capacitance either from left side of circuit (cable) or differential capacitance from the op amp itself.

Comment: @Ernesto that is current source sensor which connect top opamp

Answer (score 1):

C1 is probably there to represent the unwanted parasitic capacitances from the sensor, cable, the input capacitance of the amplifier as well as strays.

It is one of the reasons that Cf is needed to stabilize the circuit as Rf and C1 create a phase delay which in conjunction with the phase shift in the amplifier reduces phase margin and can cause instability.

Ideally, C1 should be zero but that isn't possible so it should be kept as low as possible. As it increases the bandwidth will be reduced, there is a higher chance of instability and noise will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Vin- source may have some pF on the sensor and connections (cable) but not always enough if you choose a high DC gain.

For a flat gain response, Rfb/Rs (source ) = DC gain=(Cs+C1)/Cfb = AC gain , that is if you want a flat frequency response. Otherwise there may be a difference in your DC gain and AC gain where the impedance of either C becomes lower than it’s shunt R and then the AC gain is your inverse C ratio.